# Beamer: Creating a slide with short, centered, prominent text

Tags: beamer, presentations

Between the introductory slides and the meat of my presentation done in Beamer, I would like to add one slide with the text: "Coming up: Our Work". Or some such. This is the only text on this slide, and it should appear centered on the slide. Is there a built-in and/or recommended way of doing this?

If there is no built-in way to make such a "filler slide between sections", I guess I could typeset a single slide with the required text centered on the page using \hfill and \vfill "on all sides" of the text. But what would be a good font/color scheme for this text? In particular, if I wanted this text to look like a frame title, but centered on the page, then how could I achieve this? What are the font commands for this, and is hfill/vfill a good way to center text on the slide?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

A blank slide is easy to produce by adding the argument `plain`. By also adding `c` you center the text on the page (you also have the options `t`: top and `b`: bottom). Note that you must also omit the frame title.

```
\begin{frame}[plain,c]
%\frametitle{A first slide}

\begin{center}
\Huge Coming up: Our Work
\end{center}

\end{frame}
```

As for text type face and colour, I do not want to make any specific suggestions. For the type face, use the type face you use in the presentation, mixing too many type faces udually is not a good idea. The colour depnds on you colour scheme. If you want it to "scream" then use red or some other bright colour. You can always chose something that clearly deviates from the colour scheme you use but on the whole having too many colours that do not fit the scheme may jsut make the presentation look messy.

Comment: Thank you. How could I make some text have the font/colour of frame titles? I think this colour scheme suits well for my purpose, but I don't know how to apply this scheme to arbitrary text.

Comment: Just using \begin{center} my text \end{center} (without the [plain, c] options) seems to work for me. Now I need to find out how to set the colour of this text to the colour of usual frame titles, and I am done :). Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me:


 `\begin{center}
\usebeamerfont*{frametitle}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}
 Next: Our Work
\end{center}`

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to make it render the text as large as possible, i.e. make it use the remaining vertical and horizontal space?  I don't necessarily want to manually select `\Huge`.

Comment: @gphilip Although a bit late, I would suggest putting your solution as solution instead of in a comment. It helped me as I had the exact same requirement but answers stand out more than comments on answers. Your comment is more accurate than the (still good) answer